# Customizing our list forms using Power App is not get reflected inside SharePoint mobile app

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, list-form, mobile, powerapps-forms

Inside our SharePoint online site we have list forms (New & Edit list forms) that have been customized using these methods:-

1. PowerApp.
2. Adding custom script inside classic UI.
3. Hiding some fields inside the New list form using powerapp.

those customizations are working well if we access the site using desktop web browser or mobile web browser, but if we access the site using SharePoint Mobile app, those customization are lost. so can anyone advice on this issue? how we can reflect/do our customization inside SharePoint mobile app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint mobile app does not support PowerApps yet. As far as I can tell it's not even on the Roadmap yet.

If you agree with me that this feature is important, can you please vote for it here? 
https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/264636-general/suggestions/33836473-support-mobile-app-add-support-for-powerapps-form